# How can we reduce the number of blank tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-wiki, data-explorer

There are already some SEDE queries out there to get you all tags that lack a wiki. Unfortunately, it's just enabling plagiarized, poor quality wikis that may or may not actually reflect how a tag is used in the wild. But we already knew that.

There's also a number of tags that just shouldn't exist. Unless you actually use the technology, you probably don't know if it needs a tag.

Which tags would I be qualified to write wikis for? (Or decide that no tag is needed?)

Can someone write an SEDE query that checks to see what tags I have asked/answered questions (more than X times) in that have no tag wiki (or a short, incomplete one)?

Comment: No. Most of these tags are bad anyway, and should be removed

Comment: @Braiam Removing the tag will also remove the blank wiki. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough that there's more than option I'm considering with this.

Comment: A first attempt is here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/481101 but it doesn't take into account the numbers of answers. Looks like you have none :).

Comment: @Tunaki That makes sense because I usually only pick tags when there's a wiki. (But I do answer questions with tags without wikis).

Comment: @Laurel Oh? Maybe the query is broken then... :( (note that SEDE updates once a week only).

Comment: perhaps we could allow voting on the tag wikis, then bad ones would end up with the creator getting downvotes.

Comment: @RobertLongson For a second there I thought that you were commenting on [another one of my posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323870). Weird, right? :)

Comment: @Laurel seems a bit buried, why not create it as a feature request question?

Comment: @RobertLongson I think I might post on MSE. I think it would be a worthwhile feature network wide and Documentation seems to be only addressing the problem with SO tagging.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/481213?UserId=6083675) you have to supply 2 wiki's:

```
select p.id as [Post Link]
     , p.owneruserid as [User Link]
     , t.tagname
     , (case when t.WikiPostId is null and t.excerptPostId is null
            then 'No Wiki/NoExcerpt'
            when t.WikiPostId is null 
            then 'No Wiki'
            when t.excerptPostId is null 
            then 'No Excerpt'
            else '???'
            end) as [What is missing]
from posts p -- all posts ...
inner join posttags pt -- with their all tags ...
        on pt.postid = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id) -- for answers, use the question
inner join tags t -- find a single tag
        on t.id = pt.tagid 
where p.owneruserid = ##userid:int?6083675## -- post belongs to a user
and (t.excerptPostId is null -- where the excerpt foreignkey is null
or t.WikiPostId is null) -- or the wiki foreignkey is null
```

[image: no wikis for posts from a user]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated weekly, on Sunday so your most recent posts might not be in the posts table yet.

Comment: Hey rene thanks for the query! I simplified it a bit to only show the tagname/what is missing and to remove duplicate entries, you can check it out here if you wish: [Tag Wikis I might be able to provide](http://data.stackexchange.com/gaming/query/581815/tag-wikis-i-might-be-able-to-provide). I also considered taking the user's tag score into consideration but that's a problem for another day :)