# What to do about undefined (no description) tags? (Example: [react-templates])

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I encountered the tag [react-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-templates) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184610/binding-functions-in-react-templates). I didn't know what it means so I looked at the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35932423/1) and there is none. I see that there are 3 other questions tagged [react-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-templates) that seem to refer to the npm package [`react-templates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-templates).

I retagged the original question with [react-jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-jsx) since that's what it's actually about. I assume [react-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-templates) was suggested to the asker because they included "React templates" in their title (though there's nothing in the question to suggest it's related to the npm package.)

1. I was really surprised to see that a tag can be created with zero description. Why is that?
2. What's supposed to happen in a case like this? Update the description to match the apparent usage?

Comment: another example is [vbox] vs [virtualbox]

Comment: The system doesn't offer an option to add a description when you create a tag and it looks to me pretty complicated to have included in the post question workflow somehow. So you always first create the tag and later bother about the description. Writing a good tag-wiki is not done by simply copy-paste a wikipedia page.

Comment: It looks like your question is similar to [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322137/how-can-we-reduce-the-number-of-blank-tag-wikis)?

Comment: @rene Wow, really?? That seems like a really strange way to create something that's supposed to group related questions, and exacerbates the turf war situation that's already an issue with tags and users applying the tag when it makes no sense (like with the question I linked). Who said anything about "copy-paste a wikipedia page"? I wouldn't consider `null` a good tag-wiki either, unless they're just supposed to be free-form and not have a canonical meaning. That other question is a bit similar.

Comment: I mentioned the copy-paste not as an insult but as a [warning with this in mind](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism). Based on your meta question users might start creating tag-wiki's *the easy way* which is worse IMO then having a null one...

Comment: I'm all for stopping / avoiding plagiarism, but I really don't think anyone needs to be *creating* a tag if they can't provide even an elementary description of what it means. That's even easier than finding something to copy & paste. Example for `[react-templates]`: "The `react-templates` npm package" or "[react-templates](https://wix.github.io/react-templates/)".

Answer (score 3):

When you find a tag that has no description and no excerpt yet you're free to provide one.

There is no *create tag* page. A tag gets created if you add a non-existing one to a question, provided that you have the [tag creation privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (1,500 at Stack Overflow).

As a consequence of that workflow, tags are initially created without wiki or excerpt. In the moderator-tools there is a [new tags stats](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today) and for the under 10K's you can visit the [new tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new) page to find freshly created tags and spot the ones without an  excerpt. Alternatively you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/485274).

If you decide to create an excerpt and wiki for a tag, make sure to include usage guidance.
There is no point for an excerpt to be an advertisement of the topic. We have to assume people already have some understanding about it, if not they have completely different problems.

The excerpt need to provide just enough guidance so the OP can know if the tag is appropriate. I think the term *elevator pitch* as descibed in the  [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) is spot on.  For example

> use the tag for issues with the template language. Don't use it for template extensions

The wiki follows a similar structure, explaining which topics can be asked under this tag, which shouldn't be asked, link to canonical duplicates and link to documentation, official sites etc.

You might find the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) on the topic helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I checked out those links. Apparently I'm free to *suggest* one. Not sure your description as "There is no point for an excerpt to be an advertisement of the topic." is quite the way to put it. The help topic you linked says you shouldn't define generic concepts like email, but when the topic is a specific library / language like [tag:react-templates] I'd say the excerpt does need to be an advertisement of the topic. For example, the person who asked the question I linked thinks of things like JSX conceptually / genericaly as "react templates" and thought the tag was applicable.

Comment: Yes, I think that there are a number of things where it's more helpful to have a description. There are some things where there's no need to have usage guideline because it would just be `use this for questions about [tag-name]`