# It's time [extern-c] was interned

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

There are 15 questions with the [extern-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extern-c), and there's no tag wiki for it.  It is almost certainly intended to be about functions marked `extern "C"` in C++, and that is how it is used.  But it is not used for every question with `extern "C"` figuring in question by any stretch of the imagination.  It seems to have been added fairly recently (2016-02-02)  to one much older [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9499078/revisions).  OTOH, it was used in November 2013 for another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747146/how-do-i-layout-function-prototypes-mixing-c-with-c), so it isn't a recent invention, for all it is not used very extensively.  The tag is used consistently (always with the [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) tag, often with the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag too, which is not unreasonable in this case).  No user in the [top users list](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/extern-c/topusers) has more than one question or answer.

- I recommend that this tag should be burninated.
- Failing that, it should be applied more extensively, and given a tag wiki.

The list of affected questions is so small that I'm very tempted just to remove the tag and get on with life without troubling anyone about it.  It certainly doesn't need any extensive work once any approval to remove is given.

---

**20 hours later:**

After some discussion with the denizens of SOCVR chat room, and as noted in the second comment below, this has moved into the 'failing that' option — a tag wiki has been created (improvements welcomed — it currently concentrates too much on usage and not enough on a description of what `extern "C"` does in C++) and some key questions that could usefully have the tag added have had the tag added.  Over time, more such questions will be retagged.

A semi-suitable SO search term is: `[c++] -[extern-c] extern "c" is:q`.  At the moment, it shows up some 5000 possible matches, but it shows many false positives — it is hard to search accurately for `extern "C"` with SO (or, indeed, with Google).

If the consensus turns out to be against this, it is easy enough to move into a burnination operation after all.

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: After some chat on SOCVR, I'll go add a tag wiki description, and think about finding other questions that should be tagged with the tag so it is more generally useful for finding questions.

Comment: So, you are against removing the tag, despite nobody actively or passively answering these questions? Why?

Comment: @Braiam: If you assess the tag using the four questions, it is a potentially useful tag that was missing a tag wiki and consistent application.  It is easy enough to give it a tag wiki; it now has one. I don't doubt it could be improved.  It also now has a few more questions with the tag.  It was always an "it could go either way" tag.

Comment: Err... you know people don't read [tag excerpts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575), much less [tag wiki's](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323800/792066). I don't see how writing one would improve the situation and removing those 4 questions with the tag is *just so easy*...

Comment: There were fifteen; there are now around thirty.  Yes, I know that some (probably many) people don't read tag wiki information. That doesn't stop it being right to create one.

Comment: @Braiam: Burnination is for removing tags which *cannot be useful*, or for which ambiguity makes the tag dysfunctional. It's not for removing tags which are simply not being used well.

Comment: @NicolBolas what the heck? Abuse/misuse has always been a reason for burnination (tag going kaput), because they get in the way.

Comment: @Braiam: Lack of use is neither abuse nor misuse.

Comment: @NicolBolas "removing tags which are simply **not being used well**" If they are not used "well", then what good are they doing?

Comment: @Braiam: The world isn't binary. Tags that aren't doing good are not by definition *bad*. Burnination is for tags that are *bad*, not merely not good. There is a *lot* of room between good and bad. Making a not-good tag good is far more useful than throwing it away and salting the earth.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's a overreaching claim. If a question doesn't have the correct tag it will not show the question to the person that is interested in answering those questions, because *the system is binary*. Who are you going to blame because you couldn't answer that interesting question because a bad selection of tags?

Comment: @Braiam: "*If a question doesn't have the correct tag it will not show the question to the person that is interested in answering those questions*" So if the question *does* have the correct tag, then it will show the question to the person that is interested in answering those questions, right? And therefore, correctly applying that tag to existing questions that ought to have it is a good move, right?

Comment: @NicolBolas yes. That's exactly right. And that's why tags that doesn't make any good are doing harm by taking the place that better tags could have been used.

Comment: @Braiam: ... I don't understand how your statement follows from mine. You said "yes", which I assume expresses agreement with my statement about applying the tag being a good thing. You then said that the tag shouldn't be applied. That's a contradiction.

Comment: Can somebody explain why keeping this tag is useful? Why not introduce new tags for every reserved word of every language?

Comment: @IngoBürk There could well be a tag for every reserved word, tagging questions about that reserved word, if there are enough questions specifically about that reserved word.

Comment: @immibis if there's no people answering the questions with those tags why should we have that tag at all?

Comment: @NicolBolas no is not. Read it again. "correctly applying that tag to existing **questions that ought to have it** is a good move" is correct, but a tag without any user actively answering the questions is not a useful tag. Tag main public is the people that are able to answer the questions that they are interested into. Without such public the tag doesn't have a meaningful existence.

Comment: I'm confused. Is this still a burnation-request? Meaning that the vote represents the community saying "Burn this!"? It seems to be more of a discussion about improving the current tag wiki.

Comment: If there aren't many question with the tag, then people can't answer many questions with the tag — there's some chicken and egg there.  Of the thirty questions with the tag now, all except two (one from May 2016, one from June 2014) have answers.

Comment: @Tunaki: I'm debating whether to delete the question. In the second comment, I noted that I'd had some discussion with the SOCVR folks and I've added a tag wiki (improvements welcome — it currently concentrates too much on usage and not enough on a description of what `extern "C"` does in C++) and tagged a few prominent questions on the topic. An SO search term '`[c++] -[extern-c] extern "c" is:q`' shows up some 5000 possible candidates, but many of those are not matches — one advantage of the tag is that it would make the search for relevant questions a lot easier, if you know the tag exists.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying. Well it sure looks odd considering that the question asks (and argues) for burnination (so it makes the voting a bit unclear). Maybe you could edit in an addendum?

Comment: @Tunaki: The question has 'Failing that, it should be applied more extensively, and given a tag wiki.'  There seemed to be some preference towards 'apply more extensively and provide tag wiki', so the situation is moving in that direction.  I'll add an update to the question to indicate that is where things are headed.  If the discussion in the SOCVR comes to a vehement disagreement, then the decision can be changed and a burnination can take place.

Comment: @Braiam So people **can** answer the questions with those tags? There will obviously be no people answering the questions with the tags, if you delete the tags, so how is that situation any better? I'm sure most tags started off with nobody answering them.

Comment: @immibis When tags were first implemented editors actively added the tags, of course. But with our scale, if you don't get the tags right, and specially use only newly created ones, nobody will, effectively, answer your question. Tag creation should be reserved only when the topic is already established and none of the existent one captures the topic completely. An example would be the boost library, before they used just c++ tag, but the topic was so diverse that you needed to break it down from just c++. This is not the case for this tag.

Comment: @Braiam: "*An example would be the boost library*" That's not how the Boost tag came to be. It appeared because people used it, not because people edited it into questions later. That's how most tags work: people use them in questions, then others notice and follow them. Use always comes *first*.

Comment: I'm confused about what I am voting for when voting on this question. I initially downvoted it, perceiving it as a suggestion that the tag be burninated. I'm not sure if that vote is still accurate, given the changes to the question. I am not opposed to modifying the tag wiki, and certainly not opposed to adding the tag to the other questions to which it applies.

Comment: interred, or interned?

Comment: @NicolBolas no. **Tags serve answerers**. The whole point of tags is so people that are interested in answering questions about a topic, be able to discover them. I don't know what logic are you following, but considering your arguments, I will be intrepid and assert that is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Braiam: So how does destroying this tag serve people who would be interested in answering questions about this topic in particular? Tags are not guilty until proven innocent.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, tags are neither guilty or innocent, stop trying to do a strawman. Tags are useful or they are not, this has proven not to be useful since in the **4 years of existence**, it has not attracted adept answerers, nor the questions they are supposed to use the tag has been in need of having it, because they were already answered *too*, without the need of the tag.

Comment: @Braiam: "*this has proven not to be useful since in the 4 years of existence*" And therefore... what? Not being proven useful is not the same as being proven use*less*. A tag which has not yet been proven useful may one day prove itself useful. We reserve burnination for tags which are *guaranteed* to be useless. Who's mere existence is *actively* bad for the site. Ambiguous tags make it hard to know how to tag a question. Meta-tags are simply a tool being applied incorrectly. `extern-c` is neither.

Comment: @NicolBolas how is not? And does that mean that we will wait *up until infinite* waiting for a tag prove themselfs useful? *That is crazy!* The tag exist now, therefore it should prove itself useful *now*, otherwise, why have it>?

Comment: @Braiam: "*And does that mean that we will wait up until infinite waiting for a tag prove themselfs useful?*" No. It means we should only burninate tags that are either unacceptable *by definition* (meta-tags) or tags which have been *demonstrated* to be easily and frequently misused (ambiguous tags). Remember: burnination is *permanent*; once it's gone, it can never come back. It should therefore only be used for cases when it is something we would *never* want, not for cases which we may or may not want right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One explanation of why there are so few posts is because many of them are tagged [extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extern) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), which is of course incorrect use of tags.

(The [extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extern) tag in itself is a bit problematic too, since it occasionally pops up for questions not related to C or C++.)

Comment: `extern` is also a keyword in C# for P/Invoke declarations, which probably explains part of why the tag is sometimes used for non-C/C++ questions.