# Is there a place for tags which don't have descriptions?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there a place on Stack Overflow that shows all tags that are in need of a definition (i.e., currently have no definition)?

Comment: AFAIK no, but you can use the SEDE for this.

Comment: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/714378/889093/

Comment: I tried the query that rene showed in his answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. I meant in the tagwiki, tags that have no definition there. Like if you mouseover a tag and it says "This tag has no definition yet. Make stackoverflow better by entering one!" or something like that.

Comment: @rene 8329 of them

Comment: @raphael75 if you're looking for tags with missing excerpts, see this query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/714380/889095/

Comment: Strongly related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322137/how-can-we-reduce-the-number-of-blank-tag-wikis

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for tags with empty Wikis (not to be confused with Excerpts), you can use the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/714380/889095/):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  Tags as T
  INNER JOIN Posts as P
  ON T.ExcerptPostId = P.ID
WHERE P.Body = ''
```

If you're looking for tags with empty Excerpts (not to be confused with Wikis), you can use the following [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/714378/889093/):

```
SELECT * FROM 
  Tags as T
  INNER JOIN Posts as P
  ON T.WikiPostId = P.ID
WHERE P.Body = ''
```